# VueJs Firebase getting/manipulating a collection of a user

Tags: vue.js

Im having a problem with mt vue firebase. I cant get the collection of a table to another table. Like foreign key. Im creating a simple questionnaire that the choices is only yes or no.

Users table
--Name
-----Question1
-------Yes
-------No

How can I manipulate Yes and No inside the collection.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this method, but it just added another collection to the table.
methods : {
      submitAnswers () {
          db.collection('professors').where('Q1', '==', 0)
          .get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              doc.ref.update({
                Q1: this.Q1
              })
            })
          })
        }
      }